# Maven compiler cannot resolve import

Tags: java, maven, build, compilation, tycho

I'm trying to build multiple eclipse products with maven and tycho. I'm currently stuck on an issue, where a Bundle A is dependent on a class from Bundle B.
Bundle B has a package structure similar to:

```
a.b.c.d.e.f.Class
```

When I now try to build A I get a compile error that looks somewhat like this:

```
 import a.b.c.d.e.f.MyClass;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import a.b.c.d.e cannot be resolved
```

If you look closely, you see that Maven apparently tries to resolve the wrong package, since it only states it cannot resolve `a.b.c.d.e` while the class that is meant to be imported is actually in `a.b.c.d.e.f`.

Additionally, there are no classes present in `a.b.c.d.e`. I've tried both including `a.b.c.d.e` as an exported package in the Manifest, and removing it from that list, but neither did help.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Maven does not resolve Java packages, Javac does. Have you added the corresponding dependency to your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Yes, the dependency is added to the `pom.xml`. Because I'm also using Tycho, I've also added the OSGI bundle name as Require-Bundle entry in the `MANIFEST.MF`. Since Tycho passes dependency resolution, I'm sure the bundle with the required packages is on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running maven with very detailed logging, I double checked the arguments, that maven (tycho) was passing to the JDT compiler when compiling Bundle A. I noticed, that it was only passing a JAR that I added to Bundle B's classpath.

I then noticed, that in the MANIFEST of Bundle B, where I specified the `Bundle-Classpath`, I had only The JAR on the classpath. I previously thought the classes of the bundle itself would be added per default, but after adding `,.` to the `Bundle-Classpath` property the build worked again.

If you want to read more about it, [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933929/what-is-the-intended-use-case-for-bundle-classpath-in-osgi-bundles) pointed me in the right direction.